Python IDLE crashes while trying to remove a Layer from an mxd containing a lot of layers using ListDataFrames
Problem

My ArcGIS 10.8.1 crashes whenever I try to open an MXD project that contain Basemap layers.
I need a script to remove Basemap layers without opening these MXDs but Python IDLE also crashes while arcpy.mapping.ListDataFramesis running, and this happens when the MXD has a lot of layers.
I've tested the same script with a test mxd that contains fewer layers and it works.

The code
import arcpy
arcpy.env.workspace = 'D:/'
mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument("D:/Test.mxd")
df = arcpy.mapping.ListDataFrames(mxd)[0]
layers = arcpy.mapping.ListLayers(mxd,data_frame=df)

for lyr in layers:
   if(lyr.name == "Basemap"):
      arcpy.mapping.RemoveLayer(df,lyr)

mxd.save()
del mxd
print "Done!"

Question
Is there a workaround or someway to give more memory to the process?
I believe that mapping the dataframes is draining a lot of resources so the shell crashes (I dunno). I've tried to run it directly from either ArcMap, ArcCatalog or directly from Python IDLE with the same results. In Python IDLE just restarts the shell but in ArcCatalog, it crashes completely the app.
My PC specs, this might be relevant

Intel Xeon E5-2680 @ 2.4 GHz
64 GB RAM
GPU: Nvidia Quadro P5000 16GB VRAM
140 GB HDD available


With 64GiB RAM, this is not a RAM problem (anything over 2GiB free memory is more than a 32-bit app can use).
